# I need to replace white space to either side of a word

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, replace

I am pulling a string of text from a DE. One of the text strings contains the hyphenated word t-shirt, which ends up being split over two lines.

I want to search the text string for a hyphen, then locate the closest space on the left, and the closest space on the right. The spaces would be replaced with HTML.

`" t-shirt "`
would become:
`" <span style='display:inline-block'>t-shirt</span> "`

I've googled this a lot, and I don't know if I'm just not looking under the correct search term, but I can't find a way to do it.

I am currently hot-fixing with this:
`SET @HeroProductTxt = Replace(@HeroProductTxt,"t-shirt","<span style='display: inline-block'>t-shirt</span>")`

but I'd prefer a more general fix, as there will definitely be other instances of hyphenated words.

Comment: I have solved this by using the 'word joiner' character - ```&#8288;``` - which I have only found out about today.

```SET @HeroProductTxt = Replace(@HeroProductTxt,"-","&#8288;-&#8288;")```

This ensures that hyphenated words are not split.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [RegExMatch](https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch/) in your AMPscript. You want something like:

```
%%[

var @HeroProductTxt
var @pattern
var @match

set @HeroProductTxt = "whee t-shirt whoop"
set @pattern = "\b[^-\b]+-[^\b]+\b"
set @match = RegExMatch(@HeroProductTxt, @pattern, 0, "IgnoreCase")
set @HeroProductTxt = replace(@HeroProductTxt, @match, "<span style='display: inline-block'>" + @match + "</span>")
```

(Not tested - written here, plus I'm no AMPscript expert)

The idea is to use a regular expression that matches a word boundary followed by one or more non-word-boundary and non-hyphen characters, followed by hyphen, followed by one or more non-word-boundary characters and finally a word boundary and replace it with the text you want.

Comment: I'll look into this further, thank you